# Business object model to track links between objects - Business Impact Analysis

Tags: dependencies, modeling, dependency-management

can anyone perhaps indicate some software that I can use that will visually display links between applications - databases etc. I have the data in a SQL repository, but business wants this nice GUI thing so that they can understand it, and I cannot really find anything that will do it nicely. The closest I get is a software package called Troux, but you have to manually publish every time data changes.

If possible, something free would be best.

I managed to figure out that the correct term to use here is Business Impact Analysis.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It looks to me that a tree is not really appropriate as links may form cycles. Perhaps look at http://people.hofstra.edu/geotrans/eng/ch2en/meth2en/connectivitymatrix.html

Comment: @mozillanerd - not quite what I was looking for, but thanks. That method is just a way to present the data differently, now me being a developer/sql guy understands that, but the board likes pretty pictures, you know what I mean. But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that this is not really possible without spending a lot of money, therefore after 12 months, this is the answer.